# Proving a basis for Weyl Algebra using representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

> Show that a basis for a Weyl Algebra $A_q$ is $\{x^iy^j,i , j \geq 0 \}$
>
> The proof that $x^iy^j$ are linearly independent is based on representation theory(1). Namely, let $a$ be a variable, and $E=t^a k[a][t,t^{-1}] $ (here $t^a$ is just a formal symbol, so really $E=k[a][t,t^{-1}]$). Then $E$ is a representation of $A$ with action given by $xf=tf$ and $yf=f'$ . Suppose now that we have a nontrivial linear relation $\sum c_{ij} x^i y^j=0$ (2). Then the operator
>
> $$L  = \sum c_{ij}t^i ( \frac{d}{dt})^j$$
>
> acts by zero in $E$. ....

1. How can linear independence of a spanning set be shown through representation theory? I am seeking a big picture idea.
2. What is meant by a non trivial linear relation..?
3. What does it mean to act by zero in E?